# tracking eksctl cluster create progress

Tags: amazon-eks, eksctl

We have flow which creates the cluster using "eksctl create cluster" command. Since it can take long time and the pod that is executing this command can die.  Is there a way to know the cluster creation progress, so that the next steps after create cluster can be initiated?

Comment: What are you using to execute this command? Since you mentioned that there are other steps that will be done after executing eksctl, this means you are automating the process. Is it a bash script? a pipeline? what tools are you using?

Comment: This is being called from an application which handles the lifecycle of a cluster.  the application is implemented in golang. we are calling cobra method that calls the create cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is being run as part of a CD process (eg Jenkins) and the executors/runners are pods which is why you need to verify the status of the stack.

The best way to check the status of the cluster stack is by using the stack name and the AWS CLI.

eksctl always creates a stack named `eksctl-$CLUSTER_NAME-cluster` which you can use to query the cluster status. Replace `$CLUSTER_NAME` with your actual cluster name. There are other stacks that get created (eg add ons, node groups) but that stack will tell you if the control plane is available.

You can wait for the stack to finish with the [wait](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/wait/stack-create-complete.html) sub command. In your runner or script that executes you should put this command before the next step

```
aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete --stack-name eksctl-$CLUSTER_NAME-cluster
```

This will poll the API every 30 seconds and once the stack has completed will exit 0. It will fail with an exit code 255 if the stack is not created in an hour (120 attempts).

When the stack has been created successfully your next step should execute automatically.